# How to configure between pages role control automation in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8rAp.jpg)

every time the route information changes, it should get the user's role information and then check it before going to the page he wants to go to.

If the permissions of the page and the user role match, it should load the page and allow access.

If there is no access permission, it should redirect the user to the error page without loading the page.

I need an algorithm that will capture all pages in "user_app" in "Next.js" and manage access by providing control.

---

1- When the user wants to enter a page, I got the path information.

2- I got the data where the page permissions are defined in the process.env with the path information.

3- I got the user role information from the cookie/token.

4- I compared the role information with the page permissions. If the user has permission, they can enter the page, if not, they will be redirected to the 404 page.

Problem: This control structure works when the user enters the page he wants to go to. and it makes that page accessible for a very short time. (while the control function is running)... as I added in the picture, the new page should be checked before loading and after the permission is granted, the page data should be loaded and run.

note: this function is triggered in app_js every time the page changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserLogout from '../UserLogout';
import decrypted from '../crypto/decrypted';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';


export default async function RolePageCheck() {
    try {
        const router = useRouter(); 
        //kullanıcı hangi sayfada onu alıyoruz.
        const path = router.pathname;    
        //public erişebilir sayfaları aldık

        //sadece izinle girilebilen sayfaları aldık
        const pageRoles = process.env.pageLinks[path];

        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/token/${"GET"}`).then((value) => {
            //cookie var ise kullanıcı bilgilerini alıyoruz.
            if(value.data.Acoount !== null && value.data.Acoount !== undefined && value.data.success === true){ 

                const decryptedValue = decrypted(value.data.Acoount);
                const userRole = decryptedValue.role;

                if(pageRoles.includes(userRole) && ( !pageRoles.includes(0) || path==="/")){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return router.replace("/404");
                }
            }
            else if(pageRoles.includes(0)){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return router.replace("/404");
            }
        });
        
    } catch (error) {
        
        return { success: false, message: error.message };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with `router.events`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // on initial load - run auth check
    authCheck(router.asPath);

    // on route change start - hide page content by setting authorized to false
    const hideContent = () => setAuthorized(false);
    const logAction = () => {
      console.log('routeChangeStart');
    };
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', logAction);
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', hideContent);

    // on route change complete - run auth check
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', authCheck);

    // unsubscribe from events in useEffect return function
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', logAction);
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', hideContent);
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', authCheck);
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```